# Delete and insert is not working in a block in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, exception

I want that in a single transaction in want to delete and insert but if no row delete then it should raise and error else insert(Multiple insert and delete statement). This statement deleting the data but not inserting it.
What I have tried:

I have removed the raise error also then this is deleting but not inserting the records,

If i write the delete statement in down then it is inserting but not deleting.

If no rows deleted then i have to raise an error for a block.,else it should run as the given statement. this is sample it contains,500(around) insert or delete script in a transaction.

transaction Also should thrown error if transaction failed.

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (1);

   BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (1);

      DELETE FROM CMC_BSDL_DETAILS
            WHERE PDBC_PFX = 'CW6F';

      COMMIT;

      IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0
      THEN
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20101, 'No 
    record deleted');
      END IF;


      DELETE FROM CMC_BSTX_SUM_TEXT
            WHERE PDBC_PFX = 'CW6F';

      COMMIT;

      IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0
      THEN
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20101, 'No 
       record deleted');
      END IF;


      INSERT INTO CMC_BSDL_DETAILS (PDBC_PFX,
                                    BSDL_TYPE,
                                    BSDL_NTWK_IND,
                                    BSDL_EFF_DT,
                                    BSDL_COPAY_AMT,
                                    BSDL_DEDE_AMT,
                                    BSDL_COIN_PCT,
                                    BSDL_LTLT_AMT,
                                    BSDL_TERM_DT,
                                    BSDL_LT_TYPE,
                                    BSDL_LT_PERIOD,
                                    BSDL_LT_COUNTER,
                                    BSDL_TIER,
                                    BSDL_COV_IND,
                                    BSDL_STOPLOSS_AMT,
                                    BSDL_STOPLOSS_TYPE,
                                    BSDL_BEG_MMDD,
                                    BSDL_USER_LABEL1,
                                    BSDL_USER_DATA1,
                                    BSDL_USER_LABEL2,
                                    BSDL_USER_DATA2,
                                    BSDL_USER_LABEL3,
                                    BSDL_USER_DATA3,
                                    BSDL_USER_LABEL4,
                                    BSDL_USER_DATA4,
                                    BSDL_USER_LABEL5,
                                    BSDL_USER_DATA5,
                                    BSDL_USER_LABEL6,
                                    BSDL_USER_DATA6,
                                    BSDL_LOCK_TOKEN,
                                    ATXR_SOURCE_ID,
                                    SYS_LAST_UPD_DTM,
                                    SYS_USUS_ID,
                                    SYS_DBUSER_ID)
           VALUES (
                     'CW6F',
                     'AAMB',
                     'A',
                     TO_TIMESTAMP ('01/01/1990 
            00:00:00',
                                   'MM/DD/YYYY 
            HH24:MI:SS.FF'),
                     250.00,
                     0.00,
                     0.00,
                     0.00,
                     TO_TIMESTAMP ('12/31/9999 
            00:00:00',
                                   'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF'),
                     ' ',
                     ' ',
                     ' ',
                     0,
                     ' ',
                     0.00,
                     ' 
             ',
                     0,
                     ' ',
                     ' ',
                     ' ',
                     ' ',
                     ' ',
                     ' ',
                     ' ',
                     ' ',
                     ' ',
                     ' ',
                     ' ',
                     ' 
                ',
                     1,
                     TO_TIMESTAMP ('01/01/1753 00:00:00',
                                   'MM/DD/YYYY 
         HH24:MI:SS.FF'),
                     TO_TIMESTAMP ('08/17/2017 16:15:10',
                                   'MM/DD/YYYY 
                 HH24:MI:SS.FF'),
                     'Translator',
                     'Translator');

      COMMIT;
   END;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      ROLLBACK;
END;
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you show the actual commands you have tried

Comment: I have added the code, Can you please check

Comment: Why are you catching all the exceptions you are throwing with `when others`?? Either remove that completely, or at least add a `raise` inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Perform a check **before** a `COMMIT` statement, immediately after the `DELETE`.
Just move the `COMMIT` after the `IF ... END IF` statement:

```
  DELETE FROM CMC_BSDL_DETAILS
        WHERE PDBC_PFX = 'CW6F';

  IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0
  THEN
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20101, 'No record deleted');
  END IF;

  COMMIT;

 DELETE FROM CMC_BSTX_SUM_TEXT
        WHERE PDBC_PFX = 'CW6F';

  IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0
  THEN
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20101, 'No 
   record deleted');
  END IF;

  COMMIT;
```

---

BTW - if you want do all these statements **within a single transaction**, then don't commit between these statements at all. Run only one COMMIT at the end. Each commit statement ends one transaction, actually there are 3 commit statements and 3 transactions in your procedure, not one.